# Chef-client error with Command timed out after 900s:

Tags: timeout, chef-infra

Try to download file with custom resource(which doesn't have such attr as timeout), but inet is so slow, that chef give me an error:

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout
      --------------------------------
      Command timed out after 900s:
      Command exceeded allowed execution time, process terminated
```

who knows how to increase timeout?

Answer (score 3):

All chef resources have a common `timeout` attribute which should allow you to increase it for your `remote_file` resource.

See [Common Functionality](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html).

Comment: i use custom resource which i cannot edit and there isn't any word about timeout. Could i use timeout for such case?

Comment: Umm.. not sure. Try to edit the resource using `edit_resource!` as [described by @coderanger](https://coderanger.net/rewind/).

Comment: as a result, make a fork and add timout to custom resource

Comment: Didn't editing the resource work? Fork is probably the worst of all options.